# Singleton function

Tags: mysql

Is it possible to create a singleton function inside of mysql?

BackStory:
Looking to recreate Oracle's "sequence" functionality inside of MySQL for a project so that all numbers returned are contiguous and unrepeated

TIA

Comment: Why are you wanting this, vs using MySQL's equivalent functionality to Oracle sequences: `auto_increment`?

Comment: Note: there is no guarantee with Oracle sequences that they will be contiguous (gap-free). If you cache sequences, which you should for performance reasons, then they might get aged out of the shared pool, and skip some numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be able to utilize the `Distinct()` operator.

```
select DISTINCT('your field') from `Your Table`
```

This can be better understood studying the examples from MYSQL's website at:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/distinct-optimization.html

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the pointers guys, I ended up creating the function to do it after digging around inside of MySQL's documents

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE
FUNCTION KBID_SEQ()
RETURNS INT
BEGIN
DECLARE kbid INT;
UPDATE KB_ID set SEQUENCE = LAST_INSERT_ID(SEQUENCE + 1);
select LAST_INSERT_ID() into kbid;
RETURN kbid;
END
//
DELIMITER ;
```